# pgfplots: nodes near coords only for one plot

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

Does anyone know how to set up pgfplots to print nodes only for one and not for all plots?

For example, in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3PAU.png) I would like to see the nodes only for the test-plot and not for the trend-plot. You will find tex-code for [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3PAU.png) below. Thx :-)

[image: Nodes near coords]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=\columnwidth,
    height=5cm,
    xtick=data,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    xminorgrids=true,
    enlarge x limits=0.03,
    enlarge y limits=0.07,
    every node near coord/.style={font=\tiny},
    nodes near coords
    ]

    \addlegendentry{Test}
    \addplot+[black, sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=*, scale=1.0, fill=black, draw=black}] coordinates {
        (1,1.37) (2,1.24) (3,1.33) (4,1.04) (5,1.06) (6,0.82) (7,1.60) (8,0.85) (9,1.1) (10,1.03)
    };

    \addlegendentry{Trend}
    \addplot [lightgray, mark=none, sharp plot, line width=0.6pt] coordinates {
        (1,1.15) (2,1.14) (3,1.14) (4,1.14) (5,1.14) (6,1.14) (7,1.14) (8,1.13) (9,1.13) (10,1.13)
    };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{test}
    \label{dia:test}

    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just supply the `nodes near coords` options to the `\addplot` command instead of to the `axis`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=\columnwidth,
    height=5cm,
    xtick=data,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    xminorgrids=true,
    enlarge x limits=0.03,
    enlarge y limits=0.07,
    every node near coord/.style={font=\tiny}
    ]

    \addlegendentry{Test}
    \addplot+[
    nodes near coords,black, sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=*, scale=1.0, fill=black, draw=black}] coordinates {
        (1,1.37) (2,1.24) (3,1.33) (4,1.04) (5,1.06) (6,0.82) (7,1.60) (8,0.85) (9,1.1) (10,1.03)
    };

    \addlegendentry{Trend}
    \addplot [lightgray, mark=none, sharp plot, line width=0.6pt] coordinates {
        (1,1.15) (2,1.14) (3,1.14) (4,1.14) (5,1.14) (6,1.14) (7,1.14) (8,1.13) (9,1.13) (10,1.13)
    };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{test}
    \label{dia:test}

    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```